# Read data from csv file and print unique, duplicate and invalid data separately

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file where I have to read the csv file and print unique, Duplicate and invalid elements separately.
Here is the code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

import java.util.HashSet;

public class InputData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\e.csv"));
        String line = null;
        HashSet<String> lines = new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<String> lines1 = new HashSet<>();

        System.out.println("Unique List:-  ");
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            {   
            try {
                if (lines.add(line)) {
                    String[] part = line.split(",");
                    Integer.parseInt(part[0]);
                    System.out.println(line);
                } else {
                    lines1.add(line);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
                System.out.println(" Invalid data:- " + ne); 
            }

            }
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println("Duplicates:- " +lines1);
    }
}
```

If the input is

```
101,Ron,4545,XYZ,3
102,Harry,2345,ABC,3
103,Sam,5448,DEF,3
104,John,9989,GHI,3
101,Ron,4545,XYZ,3
104,John,9989,GHI,3
105,Gang,123,HNB,3
jftdgchj;vcvuigkuj;uygf
hvykfjtucd;gfd;gfd
```

I get output as:-

```
Unique List:-  
101,Ron,4545,XYZ,3
102,Harry,2345,ABC,3
103,Sam,5448,DEF,3
104,John,9989,GHI,3
105,Gang,123,HNB,3
 Invalid data:- java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "jftdgchj;vcvuigkuj;uygf"
 Invalid data:- java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "hvykfjtucd;gfd;gfd"
Duplicates:- [101,Ron,4545,XYZ,3, 104,John,9989,GHI,3]
```

But i want the duplicates in separate lines... Please help

Comment: `lines1` is a HashSet, and you're just printing it with its default toString() behaviour.  Loop over the set elements printing each by itself instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the default .toString() method for the HashSet like Stephen P pointed out in a comment above.

Change this:

```
System.out.println("Duplicates:- " +lines1);
```

To something like this (which uses an [enhanced for-loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) to iterate over the set):

```
for (String s : lines1) {
    System.out.println("Duplicates:- " + s);
}
```